# PHP imap_open inconsistent

Tags: php

I have a very strange imap_open issue I haven't been able to figure out.

I've got two servers, both running PHP5 with imap and open ssl installed and everything enabled.  Let's call them SERVER A and SERVER B.

I've got two gmail accounts, EMAIL1@GMAIL.COM and EMAIL2@GMAIL.COM.

I've got a PHP script using imap_open to access these accounts at imap.gmail.com over SSL (port 993).

**SERVER A**:  Can access both gmail accounts using the script.  No account level authentication procedure was needed, so nothing like disabling Gmail's two step authentication, for example, was needed.

**SERVER B**:  Can only access email1@gmail.com using the script, email2@gmail.com gives the following errors:

> Retrying PLAIN authentication after [ALERT] Please log in via your web
>   browser: https://support.google.com/mail/acco
>
> Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [ALERT] Please log in via your
>   web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/acco

Any idea of what could be going on here?  Nothing special in the PHP logs...

Comment: This is the authentication problem. The second email is not allowed access on server B.No one can help except yourself or the service provider

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to the server being blocked as a "suspicious device" by Gmail.  Go to your recent activities (as opposed to devices) and start from there to enable access to the device (which in this case was being blocked by IP address).  Then disable the CAPTCHA challenge.  Note this last step took some hours to go through, and did not work immediately.